# SSIS test, ADO.net connection with SQL authenticated user fails, OLEDB works

Tags: ssis, ado.net, oledb

I have created a very simple execute SQL task to run an insert to a test table with just 2 columns Current Date and Username.

This works well when I use either a OLEDB or a ADO.net connection with my windows authenticated user. This also works when I use a SQL authenticated user with OLEDB connection.

However when I use it with SQL authenticated user with ADO.net connection I get a failure message saying 
Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have right permission on this connection

My objective is to just understand as why this error occurs for ADO.net connection with the SQL authenticated user only. Does connection or user needs a separate permission or privileges in this case?

Comment: Post the connection strings, with blanked out p*****rds.

Comment: Hi Sorry If I didn't got the your question correctly, It is a SSIS ADO.net connection (not using any connection string). I have created the connection from connection manager using the ip address of the server